# RunUAT Error: Automation was unable to run successfully (unreal engine 4.26.2)

Tags: android, unreal-4, unreal, build-process

I have completed my setup in Mac OS and configured all android dependencies like SDK, NDK, and JDK.
but whenever I tried to package my project it shows an error
I tried with a completed fresh project but the result is the same

````
LogMainFrame: Selected target: MyProject
LogLauncherProfile: Unable to use promoted target - ../../../../../Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/Binaries/Android/MyProject-Android-Shipping.target does not exist.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): Running AutomationTool...
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): Running bundled mono, version: Mono JIT compiler version 5.16.0.220 (2018-06/bb3ae37d71a Fri Nov 16 17:12:11 EST 2018)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): Start UAT: mono AutomationTool.exe -ScriptsForProject=/Users/aakash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject BuildCookRun -nocompileeditor -installed -nop4 -project=/Users/aakash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject -cook -stage -archive -archivedirectory=/Users/aakash/Docu
ments/Unreal Projects/MyProject -package -ue4exe=/Users/aakash/unreal/UE_4.26/Engine/Binaries/Mac/UE4Editor.app/Contents/MacOS/UE4Editor -ddc=InstalledDerivedDataBackendGraph -pak -prereqs -nodebuginfo -targetplatform=Android -cookflavor=Multi -build -target=MyProject -clientconfig=Shipping -utf8output
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): Parsing command line: -ScriptsForProject="/Users/aakash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" BuildCookRun -nocompileeditor -installed -nop4 -project="/Users/aakash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -cook -stage -archive -archivedirectory="/Users/aakash/Documents/Un
real Projects/MyProject" -package -ue4exe=/Users/aakash/unreal/UE_4.26/Engine/Binaries/Mac/UE4Editor.app/Contents/MacOS/UE4Editor -ddc=InstalledDerivedDataBackendGraph -pak -prereqs -nodebuginfo -targetplatform=Android -cookflavor=Multi -build -target=MyProject -clientconfig=Shipping -utf8output
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): Using xbuild. Install Mono 5.0 or greater for faster builds!
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): Setting up ProjectParams for /Users/aakash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): ********** BUILD COMMAND STARTED **********
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): Running: mono "/Users/aakash/unreal/UE_4.26/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe" MyProject Android Shipping -Project="/Users/aakash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject"  "/Users/aakash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -NoUBTMakefiles  -remoteini="/Users/aak
ash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject" -skipdeploy -Manifest="/Users/aakash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/Intermediate/Build/Manifest.xml" -NoHotReload -log="/Users/aakash/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/UBT-MyProject-Android-Shipping.txt"
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   PLATFORM_ANDROID_NDK_VERSION = 220200
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   NDK toolchain: r22b, NDK version: 22, GccVersion: 4.9, ClangVersion: 11.0.5
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   Parsing headers for MyProject
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):     Running UnrealHeaderTool "/Users/aakash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" "/Users/aakash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/Intermediate/Build/Android/MyProject/Shipping/MyProject.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAs
Errors -abslog="/Users/aakash/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/UHT-MyProject-Android-Shipping.txt" -installed
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   Reflection code generated for MyProject in 17.2330787 seconds
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC, DXT,ETC2)):   Compiling Native 32-bit code with NDK API 'android-22'
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   Writing manifest to /Users/aakash/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/Intermediate/Build/Manifest.xml
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi: ASTC, DXT, ETC2)):   Building MyProject...
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   Performing 7 actions (8 in parallel)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   [1/7] clang++ SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.h [armv7]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): Took 106.882652s to run mono, ExitCode=6
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (/Users/aakash/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/UBT-MyProject-Android-Shipping.txt)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=6 (6)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi: ASTC, DXT, ETC2)): RunUAT ERROR: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.
PackagingResults: Error: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
LogSlate: Window 'Output Log' being destroyed
LogSlate: Window 'Output Log' being destroyed
LogSlate: Window 'Project Settings' being destroyed```
````

Comment: [There seems to be quite a lot of discussion of this error online already](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=RunUAT+ERROR%3A+AutomationTool+was+unable+to+run+successfully) - what fixes have you tried based on your research so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was mac OS issue It is restricting the execution of the clang++ file

I resolved it by the following process

1. cancel the warning
2. got to **system preferences** >> **Security & Privacy**
3. here you will find the **general** tab
4. here you can see the list of restricted files. Allow the **clang++**
   file
5. go back and try to package again